# a multiple choice question on symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [real symmetric matrix $B=AA^{*}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259831/real-symmetric-matrix-b-aa)

Let $A$  be an $n×n$ matrix with real entries. Pick out the true statements:
a. There exists a real symmetric $n × n$ matrix $B$ such that $B^2 = A^*A$.
b. If $A$  is symmetric, there exists a real symmetric $n×n$ matrix $B$ such that
$B^2 = A$.
c. If $A$ is symmetric, there exists a real symmetric $n×n$ matrix $B$  such that
$B^3 = A$.

---

I am completely stuck on this problem. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

For $a$, remember that $A$ is real.  What is $A^*$?

For $b$, you're trying to 'square root' the matrix.  What diagonal matrix $A$ could you make so that $B$ couldn't be real?

For $c$, you can probably figure out the answer for diagonal matrices.  So, with what they've given you, how can you *make* the matrix diagonal?

Comment: i could not understand thehint for (c).will you explain please

Comment: @user55420 Real symmetric matrices are diagonalizable, so you can find a $M$ such that $M^{-1}AM$ is a diagonal matrix whose entries are the eigenvalues of $A$.  Find the cube root of that matrix.  Then figure out what you have to do to turn that into the cube root of $A$.